# How to change auto-gen code in XCode 4?

Tags: ios, coding-style, xcode4

New to Xcode- where can I modify the templates that are used to add the auto-gen'ed instance variables and properties when I do a drag and drop of a UI element from the Objects View to my interface?

For example, I would like instance vars to not be like this:
UITextField *serverUrl;

but like this:
UITextField *_serverUrl;

As well as maybe captitalizing the properties or other little tweaks?